# bytecode instrumentation using ClassFileTransformer.transform

Tags: java, instrumentation

I have written a Class with `premain` method and inside that method I have added a `ClassFileTransformer` to `Instrumentation` (`Instrumentation.addTransformer()`).

I have invoked a application using

```
java -javaagent:<path_to_agnet.jar> <application>
```

However `ClassFileTransformer.transform()` method is not being invoked.
I have observed that `premain` is being invoked.
I have also observed that if I call `Instrumentation.retransformClasses()`, then `ClassFileTransformer.transform()` is being invoked.
On first definition (`Classloader.defineClass()`), `transform()` method is not being invoked.

Any clue what could be wrong?

Note: I can post the source code if that is of any help.

Regards,
Rejeev.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I just added your analysis to my entry. You can select it as the official answer or post your own entry with some details, and select that one as the official answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Possible causes

.

**Incorrect MANIFEST**

Did you follow [all the steps required](http://www.donniepinkston.net/pages/programming-notes/simple-java-profiler) to define an Instrumentation class ?

Especially the "packaging" step, which involve specifing a slightly different set of attributes in the JAR’s manifest:

> - Instead of `Main-Class`, you must specify a `Premain-Class` attribute that gives the full class-name of the class that implements `premain()` in your agent.

```
Premain-Class: my.package.MyAgentClass
```

> - If your agent uses any class-libraries, then you should specify the `Boot-Class-Path` attribute, since your instrumentation agent will need its libraries to be visible from the bootstrap classloader.
>     If you don’t do this, you will probably have to use the wacky `-Xbootclasspath/a:...` argument to the JVM.
>     The command-line argument is a decent way to get things going, but you want to use this attribute in the long-run, because the command-line is already growing from having to specify the Java instrumentation agent. Might as well keep it as simple as possible.
> - Finally, there is the `Can-Redefine-Classes` attribute.
>     If it is set to true, then the Java instrumentation agent is able to redefine the classes that the agent itself uses.
>     This is a pretty odd circumstance, and certainly won’t arise much.

.

**Silent Exception**

([Rejeev Divakaran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10980/rejeev-divakaran) got that one).

I was using `classBeingRedefined.getName()` to print the class name.
**`classBeingRedefined` is `null` when it is loaded first time**.

The bottom line is if there is **uncaught exception in transform method**.
It will be **silently eaten up**.

Comment: Yes I am following all instructions as mentioned in above link. Specifically
(1) Premain-Class is specified in manifest (premain method is also invoked)
(2) My agent is very minimal and doesn't have any dependancy with any other jar
(3) Can-Redefine-Classes and Can-Retransform-Classes are set true

Comment: Strange. It usually boils down to an incorrect MANIFEST file, but if this not the case, other tests are needed. Can you make the example in the article work (the profiling Transformer) ? That would indicate whether the issue is in your code or in your JDK/JRE configuration.

Comment: Got it! I was using classBeingRedefined.getName() to print the classname. classBeingRedefined is null when it is loaded first time.
The bottom line is if there is uncaught exceptino in transform method. it will be silently eaten up.
Thanks for all your help.