# ClassFileTransformer.transform() is not invoked when loading some classes

Tags: java, instrumentation

I was trying to instrument java classes with Javaflow(http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-javaflow/) and OW2 ASM library (http://asm.ow2.org/). I set up the javaagent and use Instrumentation.addTransformer() to register my transformer to instrument classes at load time. Inside the transformer, I check whether a class needs to be instrumented. If yes, the instrumentation is performed.

The symptom:
In summary: transform() is not invoked on class load after some classes are loaded and instrumented.

In more details:
Everything works pretty well. premain gets invoked correctly, and my transformer gets invoked on the first few classes loaded. After a specific class, say Foo, is instrumented, suddenly things start to go terribly wrong. I can see classes being loaded (via -verbose:class messages), but transform() method is not invoked on these classes. These classes are modifiable. If I choose not to instrument class Foo, all other classes are loaded and instrumented correctly.

More information that might be useful to diagnose the issue:
1. I was thinking maybe some exception was raised inside transform() when instrumenting class Foo. Then I enclosed the code in transform() inside a try-catch statement. However, no exceptions were caught.
2. It seems that not only class Foo can trigger the issue. Some other classes (that I don't need to instrument but are instrumented for testing purpose) can also trigger this issue. I cannot find much similarities among classes that might trigger the issue.
3. If inside transform(), I do not perform any instrumentation, all class load are hooked by transform() properly.

Does any one have any idea of what's causing the issue? If necessary, I can provide more information on what I'm doing.

**Update**: a minimum example to show the symptom:
The directory structure is the following:

```
src\
    instrumentation\
        Instrumentor.java
    test\
        InstrumentationTest.java
        TestRunnable.java
lib\
    asm-4.0.jar
    asm-commons-4.0.jar
    asm-util-4.0.jar
    commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
    asm-analysis-4.0.jar
    asm-tree-4.0.jar
    commons-javaflow-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here is the content of Instrumentor.java:

```
package instrumentation;

import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

import org.apache.commons.javaflow.bytecode.transformation.ResourceTransformer;
import org.apache.commons.javaflow.bytecode.transformation.asm.AsmClassTransformer;

public class Instrumentor implements ClassFileTransformer {
    public static void premain(String agentArguments,
        Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Executing premain");
            instrumentation.addTransformer(new Instrumentor());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static String[] toInstrument = new String[] { "test/InstrumentationTest", "test/TestRunnable" };

    // static String[] toInstrument = new String[] { "test/TestRunnable" };

    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
        Class redefiningClass, ProtectionDomain domain, byte[] bytes)
        throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        try {
            ResourceTransformer continuationTransformer = new AsmClassTransformer();
            if (className.equals("test/TestRunnable") || className.equals("test/InstrumentationTest")) {
                System.out.println(className + " intercepted.");
            }
            for (String ti : toInstrument) {
                if (className.equals(ti)) {
                    System.out.println("Instrumenting " + className);
                    byte[] continuationClass = continuationTransformer.transform(bytes);
                    return continuationClass;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // System.out.println("Not instrumented. " + className);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Then the content of InstrumentationTest.java:

```
package test;
public class InstrumentationTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Runnable r = new TestRunnable();
        r.run();
    }
}
```

And finally the content of TestRunnable.java:

```
package test;
public class TestRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

A sample build file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project" default="package" basedir=".">
  <fileset id="lib" dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
  <pathconvert property="libs" refid="lib" pathsep=":" />
  <target name="compile" description="compile class files.">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
      </classpath>
    </javac>
  </target>
  <target name="package" description="build the jar file from the compiled classes." depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build" />
    <jar jarfile="build/agent.jar" basedir="build/classes">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Premain-Class" value="instrumentation.Instrumentor" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>
  <target name="run" description="run the test" depends="package" >
    <java fork="true" classname="test.InstrumentationTest">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
        <pathelement path="./build/classes" />
      </classpath>
      <jvmarg value="-Xbootclasspath/p:${libs}" />
      <jvmarg value="-javaagent:./build/agent.jar" />
    </java>
  </target>
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build" />
  </target>
</project>
```

Then if you run "ant run" you'll find that only InstrumentationTest is instrumented but TestRunnable is not (its load is not even intercepted by transform()). You can toggle the comment on toInstrument array to see that if InstrumentationTest is not instrumented, transform() properly intercepts the load of all classes and TestRunnable is instrumented.

Comment: I think you should take a look at the accepted answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729368/bytecode-instrumentation-using-classfiletransformer-transform?rq=1 and if none of the answers applies, please provide a sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @mttdbrd I did have a look at that thread. I'm not using redefine, and I think I've set Xbootclasspath and Pre-main correctly. I also did try to catch all exceptions. But still, no exceptions were caught.

Comment: I wonder if it's because Thread is already loaded by the class loader before your premain is called. Since you're not calling it as a thread anyway, try removing `extends Thread` from `TestRunnable`.

Comment: @mttdbrd oh, it needs to be a Thread. I removed the part that use it as a thread in the code for simplicity. But yes, Thread is loaded before premain. My question then is why (you think) this might matter?

Comment: If it needs to be Thread it's not being used as a Thread. You need to call start() not run(). Also, I'd implement Runnable rather than extend Thread. Java doesn't support multiple inheritance but it does allow you to implement multiple interfaces. The reason that I think this might be a problem is because system classes like Thread will be loaded well before your premain is called.

Comment: @mttdbrd Sorry for the confusion. The above code was totally for demonstration purpose. I cut off irrelevant part and tried to play with it a little bit (changing Thread to Runnable, and etc.) to nail down the issue. I updated the code to use Runnable instead. But it doesn't really matter whether it's a thread or a runnable. The issue shows up regardless.

Comment: @Awaken were you able to find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Did you noticed that in the javadoc of the 'Instrumentation.addTransformer' method, it says: 'All future class definitions will be seen by the transformer, **except** definitions of classes upon which **any registered transformer is dependent**.'

Did your case fall into this situation?